# Java sending gmail

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, gmail

The following isn't working but I think it might be a configuration issue.  I'm using eclipse ee and tomcat 8.  Here's the code followed by the console messages.  Not sure what to do - just a beginner at this so any help much appreciated.

```
package finproj;


import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Authenticator;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
```

public class Email{

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    Properties props = new Properties();

    props.setProperty("mail.host","smtp.gmail.com");
    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.port","587");
    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth","true");

    Authenticator auth = new Authenticator(){           
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {              
            return new PasswordAuthentication("abcxyz@gmail.com","grskxstrdsgbmzzf");
        }           
    };

    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,auth);
    Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);

    try {
        msg.setSubject("test message");
        msg.setText("we made it!");
        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress("abcxyz@gmail.com"));
        msg.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,new InternetAddress("abcxyz@gmail.com"));

        Transport.send(msg);
    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("finished");

}

}
```

and here's the console output:

```
Nov 28, 2015 9:52:47 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:Final Project' did not find a matching property.
Nov 28, 2015 9:52:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.28
Nov 28, 2015 9:52:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Oct 7 2015 18:25:21 UTC
Nov 28, 2015 9:52:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         8.0.28.0
Nov 28, 2015 9:52:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Windows 10
Nov 28, 2015 9:52:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            10.0
Nov 28, 2015 9:52:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          amd64
Nov 28, 2015 9:52:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_66
Nov 28, 2015 9:52:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_66-b17
Nov 28, 2015 9:52:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
Nov 28, 2015 9:52:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\OldSalt\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
Nov 28, 2015 9:52:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\OldSalt\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
Nov 28, 2015 9:52:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0
Nov 28, 2015 9:52:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\Users\OldSalt\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps
Nov 28, 2015 9:52:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\endorsed
Nov 28, 2015 9:52:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
Nov 28, 2015 9:52:47 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program     Files\Java\jre1.8.0_66\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_66/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_66/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_66/lib/amd64;C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.5;C:\Python34\;C:\Python34\Scripts;C:\PROGRAMDATA\ORACLE\JAVA\JAVAPATH;C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\NVIDIA CORPORATION\PHYSX\COMMON;C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WBEM;C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WINDOWSPOWERSHELL\V1.0\;C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\QUICKTIME\QTSYSTEM\;;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\File Viewer Lite\lib\magick;C:\Users\OldSalt\.dnx\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm\;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Fabric 1.5 & MySQL Utilities 1.5\;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Fabric 1.5 & MySQL Utilities 1.5\Doctrine extensions for PHP\;c:\users\oldsalt\appdata\local\enthought\canopy32\user\scripts;c:\users\oldsalt\appdata\local\enthought\canopy\user\scripts;C:\Users\OldSalt\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User;C:\Users\OldSalt\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\Scripts;C:\Users;C:\Ruby21\bin;c:\users\oldsalt\appdata\local\enthought\canopy32\user\scripts;c:\users\oldsalt\appdata\local\enthought\canopy\user\scripts;C:\Users\OldSalt\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User;C:\Users\OldSalt\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\Scripts;C:\Users\OldSalt\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy32\User;C:\Users\OldSalt\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy32\User\Scripts;C:\Program Files (x86)\HMA! Pro VPN\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66/bin;%JRE_HOME%/bin;C:\Users\OldSalt\Desktop\eclipse EE\eclipse\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.9.4.v201504302020/bin;C:\Users\OldSalt\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Eclipse EE;;.
Nov 28, 2015 9:52:47 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Nov 28, 2015 9:52:47 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Nov 28, 2015 9:52:47 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Nov 28, 2015 9:52:47 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Nov 28, 2015 9:52:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 744 ms
Nov 28, 2015 9:52:47 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Nov 28, 2015 9:52:47 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.28
Nov 28, 2015 9:52:48 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Nov 28, 2015 9:52:49 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Nov 28, 2015 9:52:49 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Nov 28, 2015 9:52:49 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Nov 28, 2015 9:52:49 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 1171 ms
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set properties like this?  It works for me.

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
```